# Wordpress Category Page (unclickable)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, taxonomy

Recently I have been working on my WordPress blog website is French https://www.geekparfait.com/.

I am using FlatNews WordPress theme http://demo.sneeit.com/flatnews/

Everything was going pretty well. But now I am facing this issue on my categories pages https://www.geekparfait.com/category/ios/. Its like I am unable to click the posts on category pages. The same issue is on the category pages sidebar as well.

But on the homepage https://www.geekparfait.com/, everything is working fine. I am able to click and open the posts on the homepage.

Hope I can get some insight from you guys.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the sidebar and the position attribute of it. Please try out the below code in style.css or theme option panel custom css setion.

```
.category section.fn-primary > strong {
    position: inherit;
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

[Screenshot](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3277883/ba9b388d665cbf35909140a35a10f496)

Comment: you may need to add !important after the position.

Comment: Yes Sir, You were correct, this was the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the sidebar is generating that can click in that entire div, try changing that **position: relative.** with 
`.category strong {
    position: inherit!important;
}`

[image]

Comment: Yes, Sir, You were correct, this was the issue. Thank you!